# db2 select x random rows for a given id

Tags: sql, random, db2

If I have two columns - an ID field and a score field that can take 10 possible values, how can I select 5 random rows per ID? I know I can select 5 random rows from a table by using the following:

```
select *, rand() as idx
from mytable 
order by idx fetch first 5 rows only
```

but how about 5 rows per ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by idx order by rand()) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Gordon Linoff