# Select Top rows and Order by NEWID() in DB2

Tags: sql-server, db2, db2-400

In SQL Server, I have this query

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM xTable
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

which basically returns 10 random rows. I also have the top rows parameterized by a number but that's not the problem

I want to do this in a DB2 query, since I have to get data from DB2 using `OpenQuery` and store in a local temporary table and from it I do the select top x rows.

If I can achieve this directly in DB2 that would be amazing since I have to get over a thousand rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [db2 select x random rows for a given id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769451/db2-select-x-random-rows-for-a-given-id)?

Comment: Or this dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

SELECT column, RAND() as IDX FROM table ORDER BY IDX FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY

Comment: this actually worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering is not a good idea, especially for large tables.
We have an ability to use built-in **Db2 for LUW** feature of `subselect` - [tablesample-clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html#r0059206__tc).

> **BERNOULLI**
>
> BERNOULLI sampling considers each row individually. It includes each row in the sample with probability P/100 (where P is the value of
>   numeric-expression1), and excludes each row with probability 1 -
>   P/100, independently of the other rows. So if the numeric-expression1
>   evaluated to the value 10, representing a ten percent sample, each row
>   would be included with probability 0.1, and excluded with probability
>   0.9.
>
> **SYSTEM**
>
> SYSTEM sampling permits the database manager to determine the most efficient manner in which to perform the sampling. In most cases,
>   SYSTEM sampling applied to a table-name means that each page of
>   table-name is included in the sample with probability P/100, and
>   excluded with probability 1 - P/100. All rows on each page that is
>   included qualify for the sample.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (0.1) 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

This feature doesn't exist in **DB2 for IBM i/iSeries/OS400**. Use the `order by rand() fetch first 10 rows` clause for this platform instead.

Comment: I had to order by because one of my requirements is to get different x rows not duplicated everytime i query it, that's how i did in sql at least, but now i'm trying to do this using dynamic sql inside the open query so i can just query those X rows instead getting all data. However this is good to know since none of my coworkers are familiar with DB2 features besides just plain dynamic sql to get raw data

Comment: Also just wondering since i can't test it out cause i don't have DB2 installed nor am I at the office right now. Is the randomization applied tafter or before limiting the row size?

Comment: The randomization is applied before limiting of course.

Comment: Interesting, I guess i will try this tomorrow instead rand(), there will be a big difference in performance for sure. Thanks a bunch

Comment: I just tried to use this and does not recognize system on the open query  `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM myTable TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (0.1)')` The provider is IBMDA400, not sure if it has any impact

Comment: I forgot to add, it seems that it's DB2 AS400, which i searched about and tablesample is for LUW

Comment: The example I provided is not applicable to DB2 for IBM i. I've added the corresponding tag to your question.

Comment: I see, is there anything similar in 400 or just plain use rand() like many examples i have seen?

Answer (score 1):

Is this DB2 LUW or AS400?

try

```
SELECT *
  FROM xTable
  ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Note that this **will not be "random" ** - the query is going to iterate over the table in some undefined order (likely the base table itself) and return numbers based on that order.  Subsequent runs are _likely, although not guaranteed,_ to return the same rows every time the query is run, which is almost certainly not desired.